# Float variable comparison fails

Tags: c, floating-point

The below program seems to look like it will run for one time but when i run in Turbo C , the output is nothing.
Can any one explain this ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    float x=1.1;
    while(x==1.1)
    {
        printf("%f \n",x);
        x=x-0.1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: This is an often made error: you are comparing a float with a double, and they may be slightly different (IOW, not equal), especially in a non-standard implementation like Turbo C. Note that the last version of Turbo C was released 1989.

Answer (score 1):

By default, floating point numbers are stored as type 'double'. So, a comparison on float and double value is done.

I think,

```
if(x==1.1f)
```

it should solve the problem.

And also `FLT_EPSILON` is the smallest difference between two floating point numbers for them to be same.

```
if( abs(x-1.1f) <= FLT_EPSILON)
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your loop condition as follows-

```
while((1.0009<x)&&(x<1.10001))
```

As because `x=1.1` in this `x` is never exact `1.1`. At higher decimal places it can have different value.

You can see here at higher decimal places what are values and working example for your code -https://ideone.com/IgrLAY